# "We" vs. "Us" at the beginning of an objective clause

Tags: pronouns, relative-clauses

Do I write, "For *we* who are getting old..." or "For *us* who are getting old..." I know that "us" is the objective pronoun, but which do I use when the pronoun begins a clause that is the object of a preposition?

Comment: Elegance: For those of us who are getting old....:)

Comment: _Us_ is the object of a preposition, and subject pronouns (_I, he, she, we, they_) do not appear as objects of prepositions.The pronoun _us_ does not begin a clause; rather, it is modified by a clause introduced by _who_. Get the constituents straight before you worry about pronoun case.

Answer (score 1):

If you are going on to speak of something that applies to 'us', it's 'for us'. The phrase 'who are getting old' identifies the 'us' being referred to.

*For us... it's a question of...*

If you meant 'for' in the sense of 'because', it would be different.

*For we who are getting old [do this].*